# ContentType Title based on ContentTypeId

Tags: 2010, client-object-model

How can I find out the title of ContentType based on the ContentTypeId, with Sharepoint 2010 Client Object Model(C#).

I have ContenttypeId, I need the title.

I just need to know, is there a way?

Thank you

**Update:**

```
ContentType contentType = clientContext.Web.ContentTypes.GetById("0x010100E745619457D78E46A59B025F467563CD00297A349446A47947AA416D334547CC72");
clientContext.Load(contentType);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

I have tried with GUID as well in the GetByID()..

I get this error:

```
Cannot invoke method or retrieve property from null object. Object returned by the following call stack is null. "GetById
ContentTypes
Web
Microsoft.SharePoint.SPContext.Current
"
```

Comment: Thank you for the code. How did you get the content type id ? I think it is a content type ID that comes from a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can request the content type be id via the client object model using the function: [ContentTypeCollection.GetByID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.contenttypecollection.getbyid.aspx)

Just pass your content type id and if it could be found the you will get the content type.

Comment: So and nothing was returned after you tried contentType.Name? can you please add more code to your original questions so that I can reproduce your steps. It seems like this is a list content type.